# Restrict access to Apache 2.4 virtualhost (WAMP)

Tags: apache, server, wamp, virtualhost

I have WAMP up and running, and am trying to restrict access to (1) local and (2) one other IP address.  I cant get this to work.

I can only get it to work from either (1) only local or (2) all IPs.

My virtual host conf file Im trying to use:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName localhost
  ServerAlias localhost
  DocumentRoot "${INSTALL_DIR}/www"
  <Directory "${INSTALL_DIR}/www/">
    Options +Indexes +Includes +FollowSymLinks +MultiViews
    AllowOverride All
    Require local
    Require ip m.y.i.p
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

With this, I get a 403 Forbidden page when I try to access from m.y.i.p.  I can only access from my localhost.

With the following one Require line,  I can access from any IP so I know it is possible:

```
Require all granted
```

Is there any way to allow access to localhost and to one or more other IPs?  Or do I have something configured wrong?

Answer (score 0):

For posterity, it looks like I found a solution.

Looks like Require Local takes precedence.  If I list my local IP range, and my online IP and 127.0.0.1 (three require statements) it works as expected.